# Recover a UV from backup file (Import UV Layout)

Tags: mesh, uv, append

I have "corrupted" a mesh UV in my ongoing edits in a file and I'd like to restore it.

Edit mode UV unwrap commands don't get close to the original UV mask that matches up with the photo used.  This corruption occurred during a mesh Join.

I have also slightly adjusted the mesh, so I don't want to Append the prior mesh.  There appears to be no option in Append for UV masks.

If I were to Append a duplicate mesh from a backup file, is there a way to assign it to the object -- to have the object's mesh replaced by the mesh of the appended object?

I see that I can "Export UV Layout", but there seems no equivalent "Import UV Layout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UV map is not something separate from a mesh; it is *part* of a mesh's data, just as integral and inseparable from that mesh as the position of a mesh's vertices.  You don't want to think of a UV map as something extra, independent thing.  An "export UV layout" operation doesn't export some kind of special information about UV, and you cannot recreate UV from it; it exports a *picture* of how your edges look on your UV map, something very different.

If the mesh's topology has not changed:

1. Get a copy of the mesh with the good UV into your file somehow.  I'd just copy/paste from another instance of Blender.
2. In 3D view, select bad-UV object, shift select good-UV object, and use a copy UV maps operation.  For me, this is available from the ctrl-L menu (link/transfer data) in object mode.

If the mesh's topology has changed, there is no way to perfectly copy everything; however, a data transfer modifier can copy UV from one object to another *to a certain extent*.  This will probably require further editing; UV pinning is a good technique to fix problems rapidly in this case.

After you have copied or data transferred, you can delete the old copy.

> If I were to Append a duplicate mesh from a backup file, is there a way to assign it to the object -- to have the object's mesh replaced by the mesh of the appended object?

Yes, you can set the mesh data used by any particular object to the data block of any other mesh object used in the file; the mesh data is independent of the object data.  To re-assign the mesh data used by an object, select a mesh data block from the dropdown at the top of properties/object data (where it might say something like "Cube".)

However, if you set the mesh data used by your new object to the mesh data used by your old object, you'll be changing *all* of the mesh data: not just UV, but vertex position, and everything else too.  So that is probably not something you want to do.  If that was what you wanted, you could as easily just use the old mesh object instead.

Comment: oops, the "copy UV maps" menu made me feel like I pitched a softball, LOL